# Calling a function without the button click event

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to call 2 functions with the Button Press and Relase events.
When I am calling same function without these events (directly in my code), they are not giving desired output.

When I click "Connect Button":

- On Button Press Event -> Call Function connect (which will create a connection between Client and Server)
- On Button Release Event -> Call Function Send Details (which will send data from client to server)

When I used print command to check the flow of program, I found that `connection.transport.write(data)` is creating issue.

```
def on_connectCLB_pressed(self):
    Connect()

def on_connectCLB_released(self):
    Send_Details()


def Send_Details():
    print "Send_Details"
    global connection,chat
    contents="contents"
    if (USER!=''):
        stat="Available"
        data="user_details>>:"+USER +">>:"+stat+">>:"+contents
        connection.transport.write(data)
    else:
        GUI.setStatusTip(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindows", 'Enter your username.', None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

def Connect():
    print "Connect"
    global connection
    connection=reactor.connectTCP(HOST,int(PORT) , EchoClientFactory()) ##listenTCP and connectTCP,to set defaults for all connections coming from that accept() or connect()
```

Comment: What issue?Mention error and output clearly.

Comment: If you are getting the desired functionality when you press the button, you could call `myPushButton.clicked.emit(True)`